# Practice initialize variable to false

Tags: javascript, node.js, initialization

Following a nodejs course(NodeJS in Action - manning's book) I saw this piece of code

```
// create server
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    var filePath = false;
    if (request.url == '/') {
        filePath = 'public/index.html';
    } else {
        filePath = 'public' + request.url;
    }
    var absPath = './' + filePath;
    serveStatic(response, cache, absPath);
});
server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server listening on port 3000.');
});
```

My question is about the variable "filePath". It is being initialized to false, but later it takes string values.

The editor I use (Visual Studio Code) shows me a warning:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

My knowledge of javascript is not so deep, but I know it is loosely typed. So here is my question.

Is this initialization to false because of something? 
Any reaston to do so?
Is my editor's warning wrong...?
Or just the author's common practice.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but why not use an empty string as the default value for filePath?

Comment: @Aniket As I said, this is a snippet of code I took from the book. And I also  wonder it might be just the author's choice.

Comment: This is definitely an author's choice. JavaScript is loosely typed and this should not throw any errors. If I was the author, I would have used an empty string of type consistency.

Comment: it's your editor, the code should work fine, it's just not a good practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason for the initialization to `false` and it is not even a good practice in this case.

This line:

```
var filePath = false;
```

can just be safely changed to this:

```
var filePath;
```

This can be done because the if/else in the following statement is guaranteed to initialize `filePath` one way or the other.

And, I would agree, it's very odd to initialize it to a meaningless boolean value too that doesn't even have an appropriate meaning for the context.  It's not even just being over cautious - it's just wrong.  It appears that someone thought all declared values should be immediately initialized (which is not the case at all because in Javascript `undefined` is a perfectly meaningful initial value in some contexts) so they just picked some value to assign to it.

Your editor is providing a warning that it's an unusual situation for you to abruptly switch types in a single variable.  It isn't technically an error in Javascript (in other words, it's allowed), but it also could be an indicator of a coding mistake so that's all your editor is telling you.

Comment: Just wondering, because empty string is also false... I couldn't find the point about this initialization to false.

Comment: @blacai - an empty string is `falsey` mean `if ("")` evaluates to `false`.  That is not quite the same thing as `false`.  But `undefined` is also `falsey`  which is the value it has with no initialization so there's really no reason to initialize it to `false`.

Comment: yes I know about `false == ""` and `false === ""` . Your explanation was very clear.